# Recover a dropped index from a table

Tags: sql-server

I use SQL Server 2017, It is possible to recover a dropped index from table?

Someone at my work dropped it and now I get the following error when I try to do a select in the table.

> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
> A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

I tried to create a new index but I get the same error

Comment: Check if you have an existing disabled trigger index...

Comment: I strongly recommend you run `DBCC CHECKDB` at this point, as you probably have some sort of corruption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dropped index should not result in that error. A dropped index should - at worst - just affect your query's performance.

Do you have a DBA for the SQL Server? I'd recommend contacting them and sharing the error with them, as there's something more serious going on that needs attention.

This error indicates some manner of corruption (maybe the index is corrupted, not dropped), and a DBA can run `DBCC` to check for that.